# Next.js: state not yet ready when form is submitted

Tags: reactjs, next.js, state

I have an `onSubmit` function which roughly looks like this:

```
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const [urls, setUrls] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const { edgestore } = useEdgeStore();

  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    try {
      await Promise.all(
        filesToAdd.map(async (addedFileState) => {
            const res = await edgestore.publicFiles.upload({
              file: addedFileState.file as File,
            });

            setUrls((prev) => [...prev, res.url]);
        }),
      )
        .then(() => {
          startTransition(() => {
            createRecord({ imagesUrls: urls, name: values.name })
          });
        })
    } catch {
      toast.error("Something went wrong");
    }
  };
```

The problem I have is that while in the `try` block I'm successfully uploading my files to the Edgestore bucket and assigning the correctly received `res.url` to the `urls` state, when the function hits the `.then` block the state is not yet ready and `urls` is still an empty array, inserting an incomplete record in the database.

How do I manage to only attempt to create the record in the database only once the state is ready?

I tried to see if I could make use of `useEffect` having `urls` in the dependency array, but this makes the useEffect trigger as many times as files I'm uploading (because of the `Promise.all`).

How could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing is Batching.

### What is Batching?

React.js since version 18 has provided a new concept called Batching. which means it defers some state updates to the next re-render to avoid un necessary re-renders.

React automatically batch state inside event handlers (like your case) and `setTimeout` callback. In simple words, when you set state in an event handler (`onClick`, `onSubmit`, etc...) React will not re-render (update the state) until the end of the event handler.

#### Example

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(1);

const onSubmit = async (values: ValuesType) => {
  await doSomething(values);

  // Currently, state === 1
  
  setState(2)
  
  // Still, state === 1, not 2
}
```

#### Read More about Batching in React:

- https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21
- [https://dev.to/this-is-learning/automatic-batching-in-react-18-273h...](https://dev.to/this-is-learning/automatic-batching-in-react-18-273h#:%7E:text=Batching%20is%20when%20React%20groups%20multiple%20state%20updates,event%20were%20not%20batched%20in%20React%20by%20default.)

#### what about your example?

```js
   const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    try {
      await Promise.all(
        filesToAdd.map(async (addedFileState) => {
            const res = await edgestore.publicFiles.upload({
              file: addedFileState.file as File,
            });

            setUrls((prev) => [...prev, res.url]);
        }),
      )
        .then(() => {
          startTransition(() => {
            createRecord({ imagesUrls: urls, name: values.name })
          });
        })
    } catch {
      toast.error("Something went wrong");
    }
  };
```

The next line is in event handler and in a for loop:

```js
setUrls((prev) => [...prev, res.url]);
```

If React re-renders the component it will destroy the entire event handler. Imagine every re-render will go smoothly updload the first file, then when it reaches the previous line React re-renders the component and start the event handler execution from the beginning until it reaches the same line then re-render, so and so... this would be an infinite loop.

What it does instead?

Let's simplify your function

```js
const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState<number[]>([])
const onSubmit = () => {
  // here, numbers = []
  setNumbers(nums => [...nums, 1])
 
  // At the moment, numbers still equal = []
  // But React remembers that when it finish the event handler
  // It will run this function `nums => [...nums, 1]` on the numbers state
 
  setNumbers(nums => [...nums, 2])

  // What do you think `numbers` equal?
  // Yes, numbers = [], and react will re-rember to run this function
  // nums => [...nums, 2]

  console.log(numbers);
  // What is the output?
  // empty array.
}
```

After this event handler finishes execuation, React will run this in the next re-render

```js
let numbers = [];

const batchesUpdates = [
  function (nums) { return [...nums, 1] },
  function (nums) { return [...nums, 2] },
]

batchesUpdates.forEatch(func => {
  numbers = func(numbers)
})
```

Got it?

### How to handle your use-case?

1. You can declare internal variable in the event handler, and use it

```js
 const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {

    // internal variable
    const updloadedFilesUrls = [];

    try {
      await Promise.all(
        filesToAdd.map(async (addedFileState) => {
            const res = await edgestore.publicFiles.upload({
              file: addedFileState.file as File,
            });
          
            // update the internal variable
            updloadedFilesUrls.push(res.url)
        }),
      )
        .then(() => {
          startTransition(() => {

            // use the internal variable
            createRecord({ imagesUrls: updloadedFilesUrls, name: values.name })
          });

          // Update the state
          setUrls(urls => [...urls, ...updloadedFilesUrls])

        })
    } catch {
      toast.error("Something went wrong");
    }
  };
```

### Advanced: Opting in/out batching

To opt out automatic batching You can use [`flushSync`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/flushSync)

```js
import { flushSync } from "react-dom";

const onSubmit = (event) => {
  doSomeLogic()

  flushSync(() => { setProgressBar(w => w++) })

  doSomeOtherLogic()
}
```

To manually batch ubdates for function that it is neither event handler or timeout callback `unstable_batchedUpdates`

```js
import { unstable_batchedUpdates as batchedUpdates } from "react-dom";

const doLogic = batchedUpdates(() => { /* batched */ })
```

Comment: This is a great answer, detailed and clear. Wonderful help, thanks!