# How does React state changes queues a re-render of a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am sorry if this question came up before, and please point me to the correct direction.

I am trying to get a deeper understanding of how React works and its concepts. So here is one. React state updates are not synchronous.

From what I understand, React runs the state setter function synchronously, but the next render is "scheduled". But how is that render scheduled? Like what exactly does React do under the hood? It's probably more complicated than I need to know, but there's another piece of information I found that may help understand.

"React waits until all code in the event handlers has run before processing your state updates"

So basically, if we change state in a function, the re-render won't happen until the call stack pops off that function? Because that's when it gets empty and the event loop can process the "scheduled" render.

Speaking of which, I believe the "scheduled" render sounds a bit as if React's pushing something on the microtask queue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77816013/18079514

Comment: Re: "Speaking of which, I believe the 'scheduled' render sounds a bit as if React's pushing something on the microtask queue": Yes, exactly. (Well, usually. There are special cases, e.g. inside a call to `act`. But the usual/normal behavior is that it enqueues a microtask to re-render.)